# Can log4j inherit xml from a base/root element?

Tags: xml, inheritance, log4j

I'm trying to reduce duplication in my log4j configuration and wanted to know if I could push similar config down to a root.xml file and inherit from it in each of the child log4j.xml files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK there's no "native" inheritance mechanism, but you may achieve the same result using an entity to reference and include an external xml fragment (see [this nabble thread](http://old.nabble.com/log4j-and-xlink-td21536915.html)). If you just want to modify certain properties, a similar solution is described [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.log4j.user/19172). An Example using external entities:

Main Config (log4j.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY appender SYSTEM "appender.xml">
    <!ENTITY root SYSTEM "root.xml">
]>  
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" >
&appender;
&root;
</log4j:configuration>
```

appender.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appender name="MyAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm" />
    <param name="file" value="logs/MyLogFile.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

root.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
</root>
```

It even works if both the root and the appender definition are placed into a **single** file, without the ?xml pi. So, the external content may even be an ill-formed xml fragment lacking a single root element. This allows for transferring the **complete** log4j config into an **single external file**:

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd"[
    <!ENTITY config SYSTEM "log4j-config.txt">
]>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" >
&config;
</log4j:configuration>
```

log4j-config.txt:

```
<appender name="MyAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm" />
    <param name="file" value="logs/MyLogFile.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
</root>
```

If you need to adapt the log4j config in an individual and flexible way, you could try and merge the root.xml with the child.xml using XSLT or [XmlMerge (part of el4j)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/el4j/) to create a config on the fly, and feed the [org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html) with the resulting DOM.

Comment: From what I can see external fragment is quite limited; only literals like path to appender can be used. Stuff like adding new logger seems impossible. Still this is best answer so far.

Comment: @bbaja42: i've added two examples that should work - i think it should be possible to put complete xml fragments in separate files and include them using entities.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that it is possible in log4j but the self named successor project [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) at least provides a possibility to [include](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion) configurations. It is not inheritence but also a strategy to reduce duplications. Maybe you can give it a try.